# Auto Increment Sql Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i am working on case monitoring system in which i need to make query which will automatic generate case no. +1 to the previous case entered. Please have a look on my query

```
select  'A/' +right(cast(year(GETDATE()) as CHAR(4)), 2)+'/'+ + cast(max(right((CaseNo), 2) )+1 as varchar(50))as caseno from tbl_RecordRequisition
```

it is working fine but after case no. 100 it is not incrementing to 101.

please help

Comment: You are fetching only last two digits of CaseNo `right((CaseNo), 2)`

Comment: yes i know but if i use 3 it gives this error

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '4/9' to data type int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One word of advice: don't try to do this manually.

The only viable solution is to use

- an `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to get SQL Server to handle the automatic increment of your numeric value
- a **computed, persisted** column to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Cases
  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   CaseID AS 'A/' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5)), 5) PERSISTED,
   .... your other columns here....
  )
```

Now, every time you insert a row into `Cases` without specifying values for `ID` or `CaseID`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Cases(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

then SQL Server will **automatically and safely** increase your `ID` value, and `CaseID` will contain values like `A/00001`, `A/00002`,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates.

**Update:** if you have a `DATE` or `DATETIME` column in your table, and you want to include the last two digits of that date's year into your computed column, use this formula:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Cases
  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   CaseDate DATE DEFAULT(GETDATE()),
   CaseID AS 'A/' + CAST(YEAR(CaseDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + 
             RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5)), 5) PERSISTED,
   ... (other columns) .....
  )
```

You cannot use `CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) ....` since that would make the column non deterministic, and then you cannot persist (store) the value anymore - it would have to be calculated each time you access it, which is something I'd try to avoid if ever possible

Comment: thanks marc your solution worked :), but i want to insert year's last two digit between A and case no. will you please tell me how to do that

Comment: @ankitsrist: updated my response with an approach that would work, assuming you have the `DATE` column in your table, too (in my sample, I *guessed* it might be called `CaseDate` - adapt to whatever you really have)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

You can use [row_number](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)() to generate AutoNumber

**Eg:**

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY casno) n,
       casno, 
FROM Table1
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT *,row_number(Partition By id,CaseNo) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS CASENO
FROM tbl_RecordRequisition
```

Comment: will you please modify my query according to yours

Comment: Can you give me table and schema

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_RecordRequisition](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [CaseNo] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [RequNo] [int] NULL,
 [CompName] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [RespName] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [fileDate] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [NextDate] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [DateOfFilling] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [District_Code] [varchar](50) NULL)

Comment: This is a bad idea. I can insert 1, then 2, then delete 1. the next insert will return "2" and will generate a duplicate. Bad idea. -1